# Operations on Nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodes

I am learning the Java XML API. I am using DOM.

I have a problem with even basic navigation inside the document. Here is the XML files I am working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>test</firstname>
        <lastname>test2</lastname>
        <nickname>test3</nickname>
        <salary>test4</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>test5</firstname>
        <lastname>test6</lastname>
        <nickname>test7</nickname>
        <salary>test8</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

And here is the code that I have so far and supposed to get the name of the parent node and it's child nodes:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder  = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File(pathtothefile));

Element topLevelElement = document.getDocumentElement();
NodeList secondLevelElements = topLevelElement.getChildNodes();

System.out.println("Top level element: " + topLevelElement.getNodeName());
System.out.println("Number of second level nodes: " + secondLevelElements.getLength());
System.out.println("Node at index 0: " + secondLevelElements.item(0).getNodeValue());
```

I get number of second level nodes (it is for some reason 5, not 2) but when I try to get the name of node at index 0 I get "#text" or if I try to get the value: nothing displays.

I would appreciate any help as I am a total beginner to all of these and fell kind of lost :)

UPDATE 1:

Here is the new code:

```
Element companyElement = document.getDocumentElement();
NodeList staffElements = companyElement.getElementsByTagName("staff");
NodeList firstNameElements = companyElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
NodeList lastNameElements = companyElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname");
NodeList nicknameElements = companyElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname");
NodeList salaryElements = companyElement.getElementsByTagName("salary");

System.out.println("Top level element: " + companyElement.getNodeName());
System.out.println("----");
System.out.println("Next nodes' level name: " + staffElements.item(0).getNodeName());
System.out.println("Next nodes' level number: " + staffElements.getLength());
System.out.println("----");
System.out.println("Person No. 1");
System.out.println("First name: " + firstNameElements.item(0).getNodeValue());
System.out.println("Last name: " + lastNameElements.item(0).getNodeValue());
System.out.println("Nickname: " + nicknameElements.item(0).getNodeValue());
System.out.println("Salary: " + salaryElements.item(0).getNodeValue());
System.out.println("----");
System.out.println("Person No. 2");
System.out.println("First name: " + firstNameElements.item(1).getNodeValue());
System.out.println("Last name: " + lastNameElements.item(1).getNodeValue());
System.out.println("Nickname: " + nicknameElements.item(1).getNodeValue());
System.out.println("Salary: " + salaryElements.item(1).getNodeValue());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get number of second level nodes (it is for some reason 5, not 2)

This is because the DOM preserves white space. So what you have at that level is:

`[whitespace][staff element][whitespace][staff element][whitespace]`

i.e. 5 nodes.

> when I try to get the name of node at index 0 I get "#text"

If you read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) for `Node.getName()`, you'd know why. The node at index 0 is a whitespace node, and `getName()` on a text node returns the hard-wired string `#text`.

> if I try to get the value: nothing displays

Again, that's because it's a whitespace-only text node.

You need to fetch the nodes at index 1 and 3 if you need to access the `<staff>` elements.

Comment: in addition: you can check the node-type while iterating through the child-NodeList by `if(currentNode instanceof Element) {Element el = (Element) currentNode; /* do sth with el*/}`

Answer (score 1):

As the size of the NodeList tells, company-element have 5 child nodes. These child nodes are:

1. empty text node before before first staff-node
2. first staff-node
3. empty text-node between two staff-nodes
4. second staff-node
5. empty text-node after second staff-node

Importance of these text nodes is maybe more visible if you think following kind of document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    text before first staff-node
    <staff>
        <firstname>test</firstname>
        <lastname>test2</lastname>
        <nickname>test3</nickname>
        <salary>test4</salary>
    </staff>
    text between staff-nodes
    <staff>
        <firstname>test5</firstname>
        <lastname>test6</lastname>
        <nickname>test7</nickname>
        <salary>test8</salary>
    </staff>
    text after second staff-node
</company>
```

If you want to have Nodelist containing only staff-nodes, you can have it with following:

```
NodeList staffNodes = topLevelElement.getElementsByTagName("staff");
```

**Anser to question after edit:**
Your second approach:

```
NodeList firstNameElements = companyElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
```

fails becaus you are calling method for wrong level element. As you see, you are trying to get firstname child elements of companyElement. But there is not any. As in the beginning, company have five child nodes that were listed before. If you are interested about child nodes of staff-element, then you have to as those from the staff element, something like:

```
org.w3c.dom.Element n = (org.w3c.dom.Element) staffNodes.item(i);
NodeList firstNameElements = n.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
```

If you have time to study basics of the subject, reading this [chapter](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/dom.html) from JAXP tutorial can be useful. If you just want example that matches well to your case, it can be found from [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)

Comment: I have modified the code according to your suggestion. Now I get "null" for all the node values (see UPDATE 1 in the first post).

Comment: Thanks. I achieved what I wanted.